# Docker Set environment variables in ubuntu cant access through php getenv

Tags: php, apache, docker

I've created a Docker container with an Ubuntu base image. Setting the environment variables through a .env file. When running the container, I can see the variables being passed through using the shell terminal.

I want to able to get the env varibles in my wp-config. I am using getenv but it is not working..

Any suggestions..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both previous answers, I could already pass the env variables to my apache environment served by docker. I just needed to add Pass env_name to the .htaccess file for each env variable.

I could then get the values via the $SERVER['env_name'] within my php application..

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable for your docker container in 2 ways

1. In docker run command use `docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE ...`
2. In docker-compose file you can set in like:

   ```
     environment:
       - DEBUG=1
   ```

   https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers

Answer (score 1):

You use `.env` file, so you certainly use `docker-compose`. If not use `docker-compose`, `.env` will not make effect. And the .env file must be placed in the directory where `docker-compose` is run from.

Whole solution could be something like:

**.env**

```
MY_VARIABLE=abc
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_service:
    environment:
      - MY_VARIABLE="${MY_VARIABLE}"
```

**wp-config.php**

```
echo getenv('MY_VARIABLE');
```

I guess you did not get env because you did not do `- MY_VARIABLE="${MY_VARIABLE}"` in `docker-compose.yml`, the value in `.env` will not be automatically act as an environment variable to container, you need to handle it in compose file. FYI.

Detail refers to offical [guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/)